# Usage of sequence in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have `SQL Server 2012` and I want to know what's the usage of sequence. I Look for a sample to explain usage of sequence.

**EDIT**

I know create and use Sequence in database. I want to know what is practical scenario for use of Sequence.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly, but try looking at this link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx It will show you the syntax for a select statement to get data out of the database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.OrderIDs
    AS INT
    MINVALUE 1
    NO MAXVALUE
    START WITH 1;

SELECT NextOrderID = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.OrderIDs
UNION ALL     SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.OrderIDs
UNION ALL     SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.OrderIDs;
```

Results:

```
NextOrderID
-----------
1
2
3
```

See [here](https://sqlblog.org/2010/11/11/sql-server-v-next-denali-using-sequence) for original source and more examples. The page refers to SQL Server Denali which is the beta of SQL 2012 but the syntax is still the same.

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways I leverage the SEQUENCE command is for reference numbers in an ASP/C# detailsview page (as an example).  I use the detailsview to enter requests into a database and the SEQUENCE command serves as the request/ticket number for each request.  I set the inital sequence command to start with a specific number and increment by 1 for each request.

If I present these requests in a gridview I make the SEQUENCE reference numbers appear but don't make them editable.  Its great for a reference number when records are similar with other fields in the database.  It's also perfect for customers when they have questions about a specific entry in a given database.  This way I have a unique number per entry no matter if the rest of the information is identical or not.

Here's how I generally leverage the SEQUENCE command:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE blah.deblah
     START WITH 1
     INCREMENT BY 1
     NO CYCLE
     NO CACHE
```

In short, I start my sequence at #1 (you can choose any number you want to start with) and it counts upwards in increments of 1.  I don't cycle the sequence numbers when they reach the system max number.